# PHP ООП, наследование и объекты классов

Tags: php, ооп, объекты

Изучаю ООП в PHP, и не совсем понимаю в чем разница между наследованием и объектом класса. Наведу пример на своем текущем проекте.

Есть у меня класс `class connectPDO{}`, синглтон, для соединения с базой.

Есть класс `class Utility{}`, в этом классе у меня методы-помощники которые выводят сообщения на страницу, или распечатывают массивы или делают еще что-то мелкое.

Есть класс `class ProductsModel{}`, он отвечает за все, что связанно с продуктами (вывод всех продуктов, редактирование, удаление... и тд).

Так вот, в классе `class ProductsModel{}`, у меня следующее:

```
class ProductsModel{

private $_pdo;
private $systemMessage;

  function __construct() {

    $this->_pdo = connectPDO::getInstance();
    $this->systemMessage = new Utility();
  }

  function delete($id) {
    //....что-то делаем...
    return $this->systemMessage->response('Продукт удален');
  }
}
```

Для соединения с базой я создаю объект класса `class connectPDO{}`, ибо наследовать, кажется, его нельзя. Для класса `class Utility{}`, в котором есть метод вывода сообщений, я также делаю объект, ибо мне проще без всякого наследования передать данные для вывода сообщения.

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница между наследовавшим классом, и созданием нового объекта там, где это необходимо. Какие преимущества наследования и созданием объекта класса

Comment: пример: класс МЕБЕЛЬ: название, описание, материал, цвет, габариты. Подкласс СТУЛЬЯ: количество ножек и тд, то есть то что нельзя занести в класс МЕБЕЛЬ, есть же комоды например без ножек вообще, или диван. СТУЛЬЯ наследуют все параметры и имеют свои.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как либо сравнивать наследование и объект класса абсолютно некорректно. Это две совершенно разные сущности.

Наследование - это принцип.

Объект класса - это... Объект.

Возьмем пример из комментария Jean-Claude.

Есть класс "Мебель". Этот класс описывает некие общие для всей мебели свойства и действия, которые с мебелью можно производить(методы).

Свойства: материал, вес, габариты, цвет, и т.д.

Методы: Собрать, разобрать, сломать, поднять на лифте, и т.д.

Так же есть класс "Ступ", который имеет все свойства и методы "Мебели", но, кроме того, имеет и свои уникальные, имеющие отношение только к "Стульям". Например количество ножек, наличие спинки.

Собственно получается, что класс "Стул" наследует от класса "Мебель".

А теперь представте себе эдакий конкретный стул, на котором вы сейчас сидите - вот это вот как раз и есть объект класса "Стул".

В вашем случае:

$this->_pdo - это объект класса PDO

$this->systemMessage - объект класса Utility

Наследование, в основном, применяется в двух случаях:

1. У вас есть множество сущностей, имеющих много общего. Например вы парсите "дорожные события" с яндекс карт. Тогда вы делаете так:

   ```
   class Event{
       public $lon; //широта, долгота, время создания
       public $lat;
       public $time;
   }
   ```

   И наследуете от него конкретные классы "ДТП", "Дорожные работы", "Пробка" и т.д.

   ```
   class Accident extends Event{
       public $text;
       public $type;
   }
   ```
2. Вы хотите расширить функционал какого либо библиотечного класса. Например Вам очень хочется, что бы объект mysqli имел метод printError

   ```
   class MyMysqli extends mysqli{
       public function printError(){
           echo "Аааааа! Ошибка!!!! ".$this->error;
       }
   }
   ```

PS В целом, наследованием следует пользоваться с осторожностью, ибо увлекшись можно легко наворотить такого, что вовек не разгребете, и поправив что-то небольшое в одном месте - обрушите вообще всю логику приложения.